# The closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k^2}\frac{3^k}{2^k-3^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are you kind to show me the way? I want to find its closed form.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k^2}\frac{3^k}{2^k-3^k}$$

Comment: It looks like math is sometimes rather hard.

Comment: why do you suspect it has a closed form?

Comment: @clark I was told it has a closed form.

Comment: Does it usually take so long for getting an answer here? Perhaps I should try mathoverflow.

Comment: @Don'tdothesmart, have you considered that you were lied to, or misread, or whoever told you was just mistaken? (Yes, it can take a _very_ long time before you see an answer if nobody knows how to answer.)

Comment: @vonbrand: the question is absolutely correct.

Comment: @Don'tdothesmart, I can't see any reasonable way of getting rid of the $k^2$ in the exponent, and as long as that is there, there is no hope to get a closed form.

Comment: The mathoverflow reference http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125528/the-closed-form-of-sum-k1-infty-left-frac23-rightk2-frac3k2

Comment: Who told you it has a closed form?

Comment: It can also take a very long time if OP has an attitude problem. Please consider a bit more graciousness in your posts in the future.

Comment: Numerically, this is $2.39446370120193816639453553\dots$ for which the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard) finds nothing. It would be interesting to see if the supposed closed form matches the numerical approximation.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k^2}\frac{3^k}{2^k-3^k}$. We calculate:
\begin{eqnarray}
S &=& -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2/3)^{k^2}}{1-(2/3)^k} \\
&=& -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left((2/3)^{k^2}+(2/3)^{k^2+k}+(2/3)^{k^2+2k}+\cdots\right) \\
&=& -\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i(2/3)^i
\end{eqnarray}
Where $a_i$ is the number of pairs of integers $(k,\ell)$ with $k > 0$, $\ell \geq 0$ such that $i = k^2+k\ell=k(k+\ell)$. Equivalently, letting $m=k$ and $n=k+\ell$, $d_i$ is the number of pairs of integers $(m,n)$ with $m,n > 0$ and $m \leq n$ such that $i = mn$. Therefore, $a_i=\left \lceil{d_i/2}\right \rceil $, where $d_i$ is the number-of-divisors function $d_i = \sum_{k|i}1$. Since $d_i$ is only odd when $i$ is square, we have $a_i = \begin{cases}(d_i+1)/2 & i\text{ square} \\ d_i/2 & i\text{ not square}\end{cases}$. Therefore:
\begin{eqnarray}
S &=& -\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} d_i(2/3)^i + \sum_{i=1}^\infty (2/3)^{i^2}\right)\\
&=& \frac{1}{4}\Big(1-2L(2/3) -\theta_3(0,2/3)\Big)
\end{eqnarray}
Where $L(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty d_i x^i=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i/(1-x^i)$ is the [Lambert Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html) which is the generating function of the $d_i$, and $\theta_3(0,x)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty x^{i^2}$ is a [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html). This may not count as a closed form expression, but it's better than nothing. Finding a closed form would be equivalent to showing that $2L(2/3)+\theta_3(0,2/3)$ can be expressed in closed form, which may or may not be possible.